# Open remote image in gallery

Tags: android

I have an app with thumbnails and when the user touch a thumb, I would like to open the full image in fullscreen. I try opening the image in the default Gallery app, but it doesn't work on all devices.

Here's the snippet :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url_of_the_remote_image_here));
intent.setType("image/jpg");
startActivity(intent);
```

On Nexus S running 4.1, I get :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=image/jpg }
```

I try several snippets of code and many were opening the image in the browser. Because all Android devices have default gallery, shouldn't it be possible to open the remote image using it?

Answer (score 0):

You should never assume there's activty to handle your intenet, so always wrap `startActivity()` in `try/catch`. I'd use correct mime type `image/jpeg`, but in fact I'd replace it with just more generic `image/*`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url_of_the_remote_image_here));
intent.setType("image/*");
try {
   startActivity(intent);
} catch( Exception e ) {
   e.printStatckTrace();
}
```